# How to update product records with Vue, Axios and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

My Vue sends a form from ant-design with axios put method when I check the response in database the value is null I've tried several attempt to pass the right parameter to no success. What is the right syntax to pass in parameter.

This is my form in Vue

```
<a-form :form="formEdit">
<a-input type="text" class="form-control" :value="show1prod.product_name" @input="show1prod.product_name = $event.target.value" />
<a-textarea :value="show1prod.product_description" @input="show1prod.description_name = $event.target.value" :rows="5" />
<button type="button" html-type="submit" @click="update(show1prod.id)" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</a-form>
```

This is the axios put config

```
import axios from 'axios'
const Api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
  withCredentials: true
})

Api.defaults.withCredentials = true

export default Api
export default {
    
    update (id,product_name, product_description) {
        return Api.put('/products/update/' + id,product_name, product_description)
    }
    
}
```

This the script I did not include the whole export default basic this is what's inside of it

```
data(){
 return{
  formEdit:  {
    product_name: '',
    product_description: ''
  }
 }
},
methods(){
 update (id) {
       let product_name = this.show1prod.product_name;
       let product_description = this.show1prod.product_description;
          Products.update(id, product_name, product_description)
          .then((response) => {
            //this.product_name = response.data
            alert('success')
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
          })
        }
}
```

Here is my Laravel route and controller code

```
Route::put('/products/update/{id}', 'ProductsController@update');
public function update(Products $request, $id)
    {
        $id = Products::find($id);
        
        request()->validate([
            'product_name' => 'required',
            'product_description' => 'required'
        ]);
        $id->product_name = $request->product_name;
        $id->product_description = $request->product_description;
        $id->save();
        return response()->json($id);
    }
```

What am I missing and how to solve this?

Comment: Your form validation in Laravel is looking for `product_name` and `product_description`, but you're never sending these values to the server. Your validation is failing. Laravel will automatically determine the best response type based on the headers, and in this case it's `ajax` so it sends the error bag back with a `422` error code and the error messages.

Comment: Really? I thought this code "this.formEdit.validateFields((err, values)" is handling my form values, thank you I'll try this right away

Comment: I have made the changes but still having the error, what should I include in the parameter of the method because the "form" and "data" doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the data with the put request, a simple example would look like this,

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
      <input v-model="formEdit.product_name">
      <textarea v-model="formEdit.product_description">
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            formEdit: {
                product_name: "",
                product_description: ""
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        submit(){
            axios.put('/product/update', this.formEdit)
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't these data already available in the form property I declared so I guess I don't have to redeclare them again but still I followed this and still didn't work

Comment: In an Ajax request, the form data will not be sent, you have to tell Axios what data you want to send, your not setting your form up in a very typical way, usually you would use v-model to bind form inputs to the vue data object. The send that data in your request.

Comment: I added v-model="product_name" to the input and textarea and added data formEdit: { product_name etc.. } inside but it's throwing error says not define but referenced during the render

Comment: I updated my answer with a more complete example, I left out the ant-design, prefilling the form, axios baseurl setup, and entity id for the put request but this is the very basic of how to send the data

Comment: Thank you very much @squareborg I'll copy this and implement in my code, by the way the inputs have an initial value from database which could also be one of the reason such errors occur

Comment: I did what you instructed and my initial value doesn't work anymore and still 422 error, I'm sorry If I maybe not doing what you want me to do properly